# why does images not show up using panoramio javascript api

Tags: javascript, image, panoramio

I am trying to display a bunch of images of a city given its lat/long.

I'm using panoramio's [javascript api](http://www.panoramio.com/api/widget/api.html#js), however, I don't see any output. There are no errors on the chrome console.

Here is the source:

```
<head>
  <title>My page</title>
  <meta name="description" content="This is my page." />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.panoramio.com/wapi/wapi.js?v=1" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var myRequest = new panoramio.PhotoRequest({
      'rect': {'sw': {'lat': -30, 'lng': 10.5}, 'ne': {'lat': 50.5, 'lng': 30}}
    });
  var myOptions = {
          'width': 300,
          'height': 200
        };
  var widget = new panoramio.PhotoWidget('wapiblock', myRequest, myOptions);
  widget.setPosition(0);
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="wapiblock"></div>

</body>
```

The [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AMy9j/) that shows the same problem:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, quite funny, with the closing `</script>` tag. You can't shorten it. Always close all tags in full form, except `<img />`, `<br />` and `<meta />`.

**Wrong:**

```
<script src="http://www.panoramio.com/wapi/wapi.js?v=1" />
```

**Right:**

```
<script src="http://www.panoramio.com/wapi/wapi.js?v=1"></script>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/AMy9j/1/

Comment: Aha! Well, I did make that change, and I now get this error in chrome console: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null `. I still don't see any output in the browser. Though, It runs fine in the jsfiddle!

Comment: @brainydexter, you need to put all your JavaScript to the bottom. Or use `window.onload`.

Comment: Ughhh, yes! Thanks. Not thinking straight today :)

Answer (score 0):

Widget does not show in composing mode. It will show after publishing.

[example of widget is here](http://codespk.blogspot.com)

```
 <div dir="ltr" style="text-align: center;" trbidi="on">

    <script src="https://ssl.panoramio.com/wapi/wapi.js?v=1&amp;hl=en"></script>



    <div id="wapiblock" style="float: right; margin: 10px 15px"></div>


    <script type="text/javascript">

    var myRequest = {
      'tag': 'kahna',
      'rect': {'sw': {'lat': -30, 'lng': 10.5}, 'ne': {'lat': 50.5, 'lng': 30}}
    };

      var myOptions = {
      'width': 300,
      'height': 200
    };
    var wapiblock = document.getElementById('wapiblock');

      var photo_widget = new panoramio.PhotoWidget('wapiblock', myRequest, myOptions);

      photo_widget.setPosition(0);

    </script>

    </div>
```